# building activity feed

Tags: mysql

I want to create some kind of 'activity feed'. For example, There are total 1000 users in database, of which there are 100 people in contact list of user X, who is concerned with those 100 users only, and want that if any of them posts a note (in general, takes an action), he wants to get that update on my page. For this purpose, do i need to make a database table, like:

```
id   user_id    note_id
```

In this table, there will be users which are not concerned to user X, so I will make some query like,
select user_id from activity_table which exists in contact list of user X

Is my approach correct regarding this matter (for example database table design and query)?

Is there any better approach?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly I think you need a relation table where you will store user_ids of the user that is being concerned and of the user that concerns.